# Errno 99 error while attempting to bind on address

Tags: python, docker, nginx, docker-compose, aiogram

So I'm building a telegram bot on aiogram and i need to use webhooks for that. So i decided to use docker-compose(i'm really new in this) and when i run it i get this error

Error

```
app_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 516, in run_app
app_1            |     loop.run_until_complete(main_task)
app_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 650, in run_until_complete
app_1            |     return future.result()
app_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
app_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 415, in _run_app
app_1            |     await site.start()
app_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/web_runner.py", line 121, in start
app_1            |     self._server = await loop.create_server(
app_1            |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
app_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1511, in create_server
app_1            |     raise OSError(err.errno, 'error while attempting '
app_1            | OSError: [Errno 99] error while attempting to bind on address ('::1', 3001, 0, 0): cannot assign requested address
app_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1            |   File "/tele/telebot/main.py", line 27, in <module>
app_1            |     executor.run_app(host=WEBAPP_HOST, port=WEBAPP_PORT)
app_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 292, in run_app
app_1            |     web.run_app(self._web_app, **kwargs)
app_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 516, in run_app
app_1            |     loop.run_until_complete(main_task)
app_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 650, in run_until_complete
app_1            |     return future.result()
app_1            |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
app_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 415, in _run_app
app_1            |     await site.start()
app_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/web_runner.py", line 121, in start
app_1            |     self._server = await loop.create_server(
app_1            |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
app_1            |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1511, in create_server
app_1            |     raise OSError(err.errno, 'error while attempting '
app_1            | OSError: [Errno 99] error while attempting to bind on address ('::1', 3001, 0, 0): cannot assign requested address
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  app:
    build: .
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - nginx
      - db
    environment:
      - ...
  celery_worker:
    build: .
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - app
      - db
    command: ['celery', '-A', 'celery_app', 'worker', '--loglevel=DEBUG']
    environment:
      - ...
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ...
    ports:
      - "54321:5432"
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

Dockerfile

FROM python

```
ENV DB_STRING=postgresql+psycopg2://user1:12345@localhost:5432/db01
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git \
    && git clone https://github.com/...My repository...
WORKDIR /tele/telebot
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD python3 -u main.py
```

nginx.conf

```
server {   listen 443 ssl;   server_name MySite.com;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/Mysite.com/fullchain.pem;    
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MySite.com/privkey.pem;        
  location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      }   }



server {
    if ($host = MySite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 


  listen 80;   server_name MySite.com;
    return 404; 

}
```

and a small amount of my main.py script

```
# webhook settings
WEBHOOK_HOST = '...My domain...'
WEBHOOK_PATH = ''
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"

# webserver settings
WEBAPP_HOST = 'localhost'  # or ip
WEBAPP_PORT = 3001


bot = Bot(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

if name == 'main':
    executor = set_webhook(dispatcher=dp,
                           webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
                           loop=None,
                           skip_updates=None,
                           check_ip=False,
                           retry_after=None,
                           route_name=DEFAULT_ROUTE_NAME,
                           app=app
                           )
    executor.run_app(host=WEBAPP_HOST, port=WEBAPP_PORT)
```

When i used **this** script without docker everything worked fine but right now it's just doesn't work. How can i fix that? (I know that my script looks weird, but it's working fine without docker and i need it that way, so i thinks that it is not because of it)

Comment: [Please do not delete and repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74332445/errno-99-error-while-attempting-to-bind-on-address).

Comment: "*t's just doesn't work*" - What does "*doesn't work*" mean? Do you get a compilation error? If so: please [edit] the post, add the compiler error and highlight the line of code causing the compilation error. Does it throw an exception? If so: please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line of code causing the exception. Do you observe unexpected behaviour? If so: please [edit] the post, add a [MRE], as we as expected and observed output.

Comment: By doesn't work i mean that i get this error above